# Is Potassium Silicate better than Sodium Silicate (water glass) in a refractory?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I would like to know whether Potassium Silicate is a better binder than Sodium Silicate in making refractory bricks.

A search on the internet on a 'vs' question relating to the two says that Potassium Silicate is more soluble, has lower efflorescence, lower tack, something about atmospheric dissolvers, none of which makes any sense to me. The only thing of interest was apparently Potassium Silicate can be used at marginally higher temperatures ($\rm50\, ^{\circ} C$).

Can I substitute Potassium Silicate for Sodium Silicate?

Comment: Your points are good, but potassium silicate also has a lower viscosity than sodium silicate for most/all modulus ratios; so your handling and workability parameters should also improve.